# What is the difference between on-topic and off-topic tags here in meta?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

There are both [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) here on meta.superuser, both without definition.

What's the difference between them? (Is asking whether something is on-topic different from asking whether the same thing is off-topic?)

Comment: Flagged as off-topic! ;)

Comment: If you looks at the questions they're attached to, not only are the tags used interchangeably,  some even have both tags. Just a guess that they were both created so that the asker could find a tag that intuitively relates to their question. If I'm trying to ask if something is on-topic, I'm more likely to think in terms of an "on-topic" tag; plus an "off-topic" tag might seem biased, suggesting that it's off-topic. And vice versa. If that's the case, it's a psychological game that makes it impossible to ask such questions in an unbiased way because the tag gives away your beliefs. Or does it?

Comment: both can be made as a synonym of [meta-tag:scope] I guess

Comment: That's a great idea @Sathya!